# What does it mean 10.171.10.1 --> 10.171.10.2 in openvpn-created interface?

Tags: networking, freebsd, vpn

I have installed OpenVPN server in FreeBSD and it created interface, visible by ifconfig:

```
ovpns4: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=80000<LINKSTATE>
        ...
        inet 10.171.10.1 --> 10.171.10.2 netmask 0xffffffff
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        ...
```

What does it mean 2 IP addresses instead of one and an arrow?

First address is pingable while second is not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a point-to-point interface renamed from `tunN` by OpenVPN that can only have 2 IP addresses.
The address on the left is local IP address, equals to the address on other non-point-to-point interfaces; the right one is peer IP address.

Due to the internal implementation of OpenVPN tun mode network, this peer address can't be ping(8)ed, but used as a router instead.

For example, if you run PPP on FreeBSD (implemented with the same `tun(4)` interface) the peer address will be another host of the PPP link.